# render array data gotten from firebase firestore

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the data inside my messages array field from firestore, I can see the data in my debugger, but cannot fetch a single part of the message. I am roughly new to react native and firebase. kindly direct me. The image below is the data i want to fetch from my firestore database
[image]

below is my sample code.

```
          const { currentUser } = Firebase.auth;
          const userUid = currentUser.uid;
          const chatroomMessages = [];

          const ref = await Firebase.firestore.collection('chatrooms');
          const getDoc = ref.doc(this.props.item.key)
                              .onSnapshot(doc => {
                                if (!doc.exists) {
                                  console.log('No such document!');
                                  return;
                                }
                                //const { createdAt } = change.data();

                               const messages = doc.data();

                               const data = messages.messages;

                               //const { ...text } = data;

                               chatroomMessages.push({
                                 data
                                 })

                               this.setState({
                                 chatroomMessages,
                                 });

                                    console.log('Document data:', chatroomMessages);
                              });
```

Comment: Did you try it using .get() method instead of onSnapshot?

Comment: I am creating a chatroom app, hence the onSnapshot for realtime update

Comment: Use useEffect() and call function where you are fetching data inside it

Comment: can you direct me as to how I can use that?
I have never used it before

Comment: I’m out right now. I will share the code when i reach.

Comment: alright, cheers, I added an image of the db for better clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it by doing this

```
          _fetchChatData = async () => {
              this.unsubscribe = await this.newChatRef.doc(this.props.chatID)
              .onSnapshot(doc => {
                const data = doc.data().message;

                const privateMessages = [];
                for (const message in data) {
                  privateMessages.push({
                    text: data[message].text,
                    key: data[message].createdAt,
                    authorID: data[message].authorID,
                    author: data[message].author,
                    authorPic: data[message].authorPic,
                  });
                }

                this.setState({
                  privateMessages,
                });
                console.log(privateMessages);
              }
            );
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
    async function getMessages(){
           const ref = await Firebase.firestore.collection('chatrooms');
                  const getDoc = ref.doc(this.props.item.key)
                                      .onSnapshot(doc => {
                                        if (!doc.exists) {
                                          console.log('No such document!');
                                          return;
                                        }
                                        //const { createdAt } = change.data();

                                       const messages = doc.data();

                                       const data = messages.messages;

                                       //const { ...text } = data;

                                       chatroomMessages.push({
                                         data
                                         })

                                       return chatroomMessages;
                                            console.log('Document data:', chatroomMessages);
                                      });
                   this.setState({ 
                    messages : getDoc
              });
            }
```

try to initialise state inside constructor :

```
  export default class Messages extends Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
      this.state = {
    messages : []
    }
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
          </View>
        );
      }

}
```

and call function to fetch inside component did mount

```
componentDidMount(){
     getMessages();
    }
```

and inside your view display as

```
 <div> 
   { this.state.messages.map( message => ( 
       <div> { message &&  message }  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Still the same... it was inside componentDidMount before, sorry I dint indicate that

Comment: You dint use the useEffect?

Comment: useEffect is used in functional components. Since you are using class based components. I used componentDidMount.  Are you receiving any error?

Comment: I am getting the data in the debugger or when I console log, but I cannot pass the data gotten into the chatroomMessages state. I am using flatlist

Comment: Try setting an empty state in constructor. Maybe this is because the view is rendered before the request is completed.

Comment: Yeah, I do have an empty state in the constructor.

Comment: I have tried everything possible, but still not working

Comment: @vincentO try this last update or share it on codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: @vincentO , after all , did the option proposed by Udit work?